# Akonadi (KDE) crash: repair InnoDB data when MySQL can't start

Tags: mysql, crash, innodb

I run a small MySQL installation as part of my Akonadi (under KDE) installation. At some point recently some of my InnoDB data has become corrupted. I'm not sure, but it may be related to a recent update of some KDE packages. Right now I'm trying to get a set of recovery tools to compile (https://launchpad.net/percona-data-recovery-tool-for-innodb).
Until then, figured I'd try SO for some advice.

Unfortunately, MySQL will not run due to the corruption, most of the help I've found online relies on it to be running. Output of `mysqld`: http://paste.kde.org/prkw3di6d

In particular, we have

```
140727  9:00:22 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 13418196 and 13418196 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 53487166 in the ib_logfiles!
140727  9:00:22 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
140727  9:00:22 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
140727  9:00:22 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
140727  9:00:22 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages
140727  9:00:22 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
140727  9:00:23 [ERROR] mysqld got signal 11 ;
```

Fortunately, it seems that only a few of the `ibd` files were modified recently. Let me know what other information could help with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't exhausted low-hanging fruits yet.

First, try to start MySQL with innodb_force_recovery=4 (or 5, or 6). InnoDB crashes during crash recovery process, so it's better to skip it. 
If it starts take a dump of all databases and re-create InnoDB table spaces.

Optionally you could check if you can repair the database without dump&reload as I described in "[Repair Corrupted InnoDB Table with Corruption in Secondary Index Edit](https://twindb.com/repair-corrupted-innodb-table-with-corruption-in-secondary-index/)" post.

Only if MySQL doesn't start with innodb_force_recovery=6 then you need to fetch records from ibd files.

By the way, I continue development of the recovery toolkit in https://launchpad.net/undrop-for-innodb . I fixed some bugs related to recent MySQL versions and made it easier to use (no need to recompile, no dependencies on unneeded libraries)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, MySQL does fail to start, even with the repair options: http://paste.kde.org/ptgsciru6 ; although it did fail in a slightly odd way for modes 4 and 5. Do you know of a resource I can use to advise as to how to recover data from the ibd files?

Comment: There are few examples in this post https://twindb.com/undrop-tool-for-innodb/ .
What you need is: a) parse each ibd file with stream_parser b) fetch records with c_parser (you need to have CREATE TABLE statements) c) load dumps generated by c_parser into a new MySQL instance